# Rewriting specific host to directories on localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm currently trying to redirect my local configured domains to its directories.. What is the best way to achieve this using htaccess?

Currently 'localhost' redirects to /Library/WebServer/Documents/ (mac OSX), i want to create an htaccess file in this directory that will lead all domains to its directory.

Example htaccess code of what I'm looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Library/WebServer/Documents/example.com/$1 [L]
```

I hope someone can help me out, think there's an easy fix for this!

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with `.htaccess` alone. You need access to the main server configuration file or at least modify the appropriate virtual host section.

If you can modify the main config file, you can add any number of [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html).

If you're allowed to adjust your virtual host only, you must add as many [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias) entries to your virtual host as you have domains.

Then you can add the rewrite rules for the various domains

```
RewriteEngine On

# prevent endless loop
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com/$ 
RewriteRule ^.*$ /Library/WebServer/Documents/example.com/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com/$ 
RewriteRule ^.*$ /Library/WebServer/Documents/domain.com/$0 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# get the server name from the Host: header
UseCanonicalName Off

# include the server name in the filenames used to satisfy requests
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/%0/httpdocs

<Location /var/www/vhosts>
    AllowOverride All
    Options +FollowSymLinks
</Location>
```

Then, you could try these examples:

**example.com** would show /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs

**example2.com** would show /var/www/vhosts/example2.com/httpdocs

Remember to add the domains to your hosts file.

[Source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html)